# HTML 'object' resending request everytime I hide and show in Chrome

Tags: html

When a 'object' element is hidden and shown in Chrome, a request is being sent to the url in 'data' attribute and the data is loading again.
This is causing a delay in showing up.

Note: It is working fine in Firefox,i.e., no request is being sent again.

Comment: This seems to be a webkit issue (can reproduce in Safari too) kind of weird, since you can still access the `contentDocument` when `display` is `none`.

Comment: share code plz.